# Encapsulating Game Entity Events

Tags: java, game-engine

I have been using a game loop structure with a tick and render thread to program games in Java.

I will use 2 examples to explain my problem. Say we have a `World` class that holds the location of all entities. The game loop then cycles though all the entities triggering their `update()` methods.

### Example 1

If a `Monster` wants to attack another `Monster`, how would it access a list of other entities around it to attack? If this was accomplished by passing in a list of local entities, would it be the right approach to directly attack the other `Monster` by calling it's `recieveAttack()` method or would it be better for the attacking monster to trigger some kind of flag including data relevant to the attack. The game loop could then also cycle through all these flags and trigger the appropriate attacks.

### Example 2

Another example would be if a `Ship` creates a `Rocket` but the `Ship` then blows up. How does this bullet still exist if it was created inside the `Ship` class?

### The Actual Question

How should I structure my games to allow for these kind of interactions? I know workarounds like passing the main game class in when `update()` is called but I realize this is extremely sketchy!

Comment: *"..would it be the right approach to directly attack the other Monster by calling it's recieveAttack() method"*  I don't think so.  It should have an `attack(Monster)` method.  Mind you, that attacked `Monster` might then choose to `runAway()`  ;)

Comment: I guess what I mean is, should the a monster attack another monster or should a monster tell the world it wants to attack another monster.

Comment: *"should a monster tell the world"*  Given any individual monster has little affect on 'the world' I'd say: A) The world does not give a toss.  B) Use the other approach.

Answer (score 1):

One of the big movements in game system design at the moment is Entity Systems. These allow all sorts of complex interactions to build up out of a relatively simple set of rules.

It's far too big a topic to get into here but there is an open source Entity System implementation available for jME3 and there has been some very detailed discussion of how Entity Systems work on the jME3 forums.

http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:contributions:entitysystem

http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/topic/my-es-in-contrib-zay-es/

Forum searches will also find a number of other threads discussing ES in some depth.

Even if you aren't using jME3 the discussion, concepts and implementation details of Zay-ES will give you a good introduction to let you decide whether this approach is right for you.